# React.js combining static elements

Tags: reactjs

I want to dynamically combine different react elements:

```
const Addresses = () => {
  const addressElement = () => {
    return  <TextInput
      name="addressLine"
     />;
  };
  const addressElement2 = () => {
    return  <TextInput
      name="addressLine2"
     />;
  };
  let address = addressElement1 + addressElement2;
  return (
    <div>
      address
    </div>);
};
```

Instead of printing the elements this is printing:

```
[object Object][object Object];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what you want to do:

```
return (
  <div>
    { addressElement1() }
    { addressElement2() }
  </div>
);
```

or you can make them into an array beforehand:

```
const address = [ addressElement1(), addressElement2() ];
return (
  <div>
    { address }
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Would it be possible to wrap the addressElement1() with a div?

Comment: @PotneySwitters You can simply replace `addressElement1()` with `<div> {addressElement1()}</div>` to make that happen. Essentially, what you're missing is to wrap anything things with {} when it is within JSX syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm there some little mistakes on your implementation. If you want to render variable you need to use {address}. And combining React component can be made with simply [, ]

Your final code would be like this

```
let address = [<addressElement1/>, <addressElement2/>]
return (  
    <div>
        {address}
    </div>
);
```

**edit**

```
let address = [<AddressElement1 key="left"/>, <AddressElement2 key="right"/>]
```

But you must rename your stateless component width A instead of a

If you don't want to use key you can directly

```
return (
    <div>
      <AddressElement1/>
      <AddressElement2/>
    </div>
);
```